# How to set different prefix for endpoints and for static content in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

I would like to ask if it is possible (and how) to set different prefixes for static content and for endpoints in the spring boot app. I have been using `server.servlet.contextPath=/api` in application properties but it also sets the prefix for static content.

What I would like to achieve is to have "/api" prefix for endpoints in controllers and to serve the static content from "/" root.

**EDITED**
Actually what I need is to be able to set only the static content to "/" and rest of the app be available on "/api"

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot uses the built-in `WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter` for a Webapplication. The default behavior is defined within this class.

I assume your controllers are annotated with `@RestController`. If this is the case, you're able to map all controllers to a different location.

Create a configuration class which implements the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface. Override the method `configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer)` and implement your desired path configuration.

In the following example, the static content will still be served at "/" and all REST endpoints will be accessible with "/api" as prefix.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerTypePredicate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addPathPrefix("/api", HandlerTypePredicate.forAnnotation(RestController.class));
    }

}
```

You'll notice there's no `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in this class, because it would disable the Spring Boot autoconfiguration mechanism for `WebMvc`.